# How to capture and decode ssl traffic from apk which do not use default WLAN proxy settings

Tags: ssl, decode, fiddler

These days I am researching on capturing and decoding SSL traffic from apk files, I have learned that it is possible to use Fiddler to do that, I have done all the steps in the following link

[Cannot configure Fiddler proxy in Android to decrypt HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509200/cannot-configure-fiddler-proxy-in-android-to-decrypt-https/52473197)

But my situation is a little different, I can decode some SSL traffic from apk files, but some SSL traffic seems does not go through WLAN, not like the situation in above links, it does not appear in Fiddler capturing window(maybe the code in apk deliberately set to not go through WLAN to avoid being captured?)

so I tried proxydroid to make all traffic go to my fiddler proxy, It succeeded, now it appears in fiddler capturing window, but it seems not using fiddler root cert like those traffic which goes through WLAN as default, so I can only see "connect to xxx" in Fiddler window, but no decryption

I even tried xpose framework and JustTrustMe, still no use(although I think the problem does not lie there)

So in such a situation, Is there a way to decode? I think the key is to both direct SSL traffic to fiddler proxy and use root cert simultaneously, but How?

UPDATE:

not to mention this specific problem, currently Could someone give me some information about how a SSL cert is used in android system, why those https links which use WLAN as default will use cert automatically, I guess it's because those links which use WLAN as default is just like use https link in browser , while cert is trusted by browser when you installed this root cert, but those links which do not use WLAN as default actually do not trigger https link like in browser, so even using some tool to redirect those links to fiddler proxy can not make it trust the cert, so they just do not use this root cert?? if my guess is right, then maybe there is no easy solution to solve this problem??

UPDATE2:

I have posted another [topic](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/are-there-some-tips-to-get-specific-code-info-from-apk-without-decompiling-it-to), which tries to solve this problem from another perspective, it provided specific apk link, so if someone is interested, you can visit that topic to get more info